# До нажатия на кнопку появляется Undefined index

Tags: php, html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать так что бы ее не было изначально(ошибки)?Спасибо

```
<form method="POST">
  ID:<input type="text" name="del_id">
  <input type="submit" value="DELETE" name="VALUE" />
</form>

<?php
$del = $_POST['del_id'];
if (isset($del)) {
    $query3 = "DELETE FROM notes WHERE id = ' $del  '";
    $res =  mysqli_query($connection, $query3);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код:

```
$del = $_POST['del_id'];

if (isset($del)) ...
```

Вы проверяете существование переменной, которую сами определили строчкой выше. Конечно условие выполнится. Нужно проверять существование данных в POST:

```
if (isset($_POST['del_id'])) {
  $del = $_POST['del_id'];
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вначале нужно делать проверку `isset()` а потом пытаться получить значение

```
if (isset($_POST['del_id'])) {
  $del = $_POST['del_id'];
```